# Multiple Columns from same field in results

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, multiple-columns

I am trying to query my database and return results that would have multiple columns from the same field.

The data in my database might look like this:

```
  id,        price,       cost,       description,        color
  --------------------------------------------------------------        
  10,         99,          50,         bicycle,           blue
  15,         88,          45,         tricycle,          red
  18,         90,          48,         tricycle,          blue
  20,         95,          55,         bicycle,           red
```

I am trying to write a query to return results that would give me multiple columns to represent each type of color as 'Blue' or as 'Red' and their id, price, cost and description, like this:

```
Blue, id, price, cost, description, Red, id, price, cost, description
blue, 10, 99,    50,   bicycle,     red, 15, 88,    45,   tricycle
blue, 18, 90,    48,   tricycle,    red, 20, 95,    55,   bicycle
```

The point is to be able to see the data side by side, I could easily do this in a pivot table once the data is in Excel but we are trying to accomplish this through a SQL query.

Any help is greatly appreciated please let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

*

So upon review of the comments below I am thinking maybe it is better that i just include the acutal code I am working with now.

My problem: I need the results from both select statements in one query I just can’t figure out how to do it. So in total there would be 7 columns

**Class Code, Lost Time Claim Count, Lost Time Incurred Loss, Lost Time Claim Average,       Medical Only Claim Count, Medical Only Incurred Loss, Medical Only Claim Average**

```
select distinct cm.class_code, count(cm.class_code) as "Lost Time Claim Count",
   round(sum(cf.Incurred_Total),0) as "Lost Time Incurred Loss",
   round((sum(cf.Incurred_Total)/count(cm.class_code)),0) as "Lost Time Claim Average",
   cm.claim_type_group

from claim_master cm left outer join
 claim_financial_view cf on cm.claim_master_id = cf.Claim_Master_Id

where cm.accident_date > to_date('31-Dec-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') and
  cm.accident_date < to_date('01-Jan-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') and
  cm.claim_type_group = 'L'

group by cm.class_code,
     cm.claim_type_group

Order by cm.class_code

__

select distinct cm.class_code, count(cm.class_code) as "Medical Only Claim Count",
   round(sum(cf.Incurred_Total),0) as "Medical Only Incurred Loss",
   round((sum(cf.Incurred_Total)/count(cm.class_code)),0) as "Medical Only Claim      Average",
   cm.claim_type_group

from claim_master cm left outer join
 claim_financial_view cf on cm.claim_master_id = cf.Claim_Master_Id

where cm.accident_date > to_date('31-Dec-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') and
  cm.accident_date < to_date('01-Jan-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') and
  cm.claim_type_group = 'M'

group by cm.class_code,
     cm.Claim_Type_Group

Order by cm.class_code
```

Comment: Is there a defined, finite, set of colours? Is this stored in a separate table? You won't be able to pivot this without one.

Comment: P.S. don't worry about the pictures; it's better to do raw text as it means people can use the same data as you more easily. If you want to draw a table [Senseful Solutions have a great tool](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) but it's always good to put a sample table structure and a small amount of actual data in a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) so that people can play, which makes them more likely to answer your question!

Comment: There would be two colors and the color would be in a separate table.

Comment: Ben I added some code from the actual statement I have been working on. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You may want to try a pivot table (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As there's no relation between your data I think it's simplest to just create one. This is one of, probably many, possible solutions:

```
select a.color as blue, a.id as idb, a.price as priceb
     , a.cost as costb, a.description as descb
     , b.color as red, b.id as idr, b.price as pricer
     , b.cost as costr, b.description as descr
  from ( select x.*, row_number() over ( order by id ) as rn
           from my_table x
          where color = 'blue'
                ) a
  full outer join ( 
         select x.*, row_number() over ( order by id ) as rn
            from my_table x
           where color = 'red'
                 ) b
    on a.rn = b.rn
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24c4d/4)

The [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm#sthref1468) analytic function gives you something to join on and by using a FULL OUTER JOIN it doesn't matter if one colour has more rows than another.

---

Ach, and now you've added different column names in the code! The principle should be exactly the same; your current queries become the sub-queries I have here.